# Swift 2.1 POST through HTTPBody not working

Tags: php, swift, post, swift2

I am trying to send data via POST to a server in Swift 2.1, however, the server never appears to receive any of the data.

Swift:

```
let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.myserver.com/test.php");
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:url!)
request.HTTPMethod = "POST";

let postString = "firstName=TestName1&lastName=TestName2";
request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession();
let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in

    let urlContent = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as NSString!
    print("Data: \(urlContent)");
});

task.resume();
```

PHP:

```
<?php
// Read request parameters
$firstName= $_REQUEST["firstName"];
$lastName = $_REQUEST["lastName"];// Store values in an array
$returnValue = array(“firstName”=>$firstName, “lastName”=>$lastName);
// Send back request in JSON format
echo json_encode($returnValue); ?>
```

Returns:

> Data: {"firstName":null,"lastName":null}

I have canvased the web in an attempt to solve this problem, however, most of the solutions are out of date as they do not conform to the deprecations and changes brought with Swift 2.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try this `echo json_encode($_REQUEST);` to check if you are getting any data from app

Comment: @DevendraBhandari Thanks for your reply. That returns two brackets (I think referring to an empty dictionary), []

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By removing the following lines of code, I got the data to return correctly:

```
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
```